# Safari - HTML5 audio not playing automatically next stream

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have a little code with play/pause, next, prev buttons. I have multiple tracks (streams) to play and we can jump between them with next, prev buttons. This works beautifully in Firefox, Chrome, but not on Safari (desktop, mobile). In FF and Chrome when you jump to the next, prev stream, the stream auto starts to playing. But not on Safari, the stream stops when I hit the next or prev buttons. What's this behavior?

```js
function aud_play_pause() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");
    if (myAudio.paused) {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-play');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-pause');
      myAudio.play();
    } else {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-pause');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-play');
      myAudio.pause();
   }
 }

$(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(function($) {
  var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
  if(supportsAudio) {
    var index = 0,
    playing = false;
    tracks = [
      {"track":1,"name":"Music FM","file":"http://stream.musicfm.hu:8000/musicfm.mp3"},
      {"track":2,"name":"Radio 1","file":"http://213.181.210.106:8000/high.mp3"},
      {"track":3,"name":"Test FM","file":"http://213.181.210.106:8000/high.mp3"},
    ],
    trackCount = tracks.length,
    npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
    audio = $('#audio1').bind('play', function() {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-play');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-pause');
      playing = true;
    }).bind('pause', function() {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-pause');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-play');
      playing = false;
    }).get(0),
    btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').click(function() {
      if((index - 1) > -1) {
        index--;
        loadTrack(index);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      } else {
        index = 0
        loadTrack(trackCount-1);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      }
    }),
    btnNext = $('#btnNext').click(function() {
      if((index + 1) < trackCount) {
        index++;
        loadTrack(index);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      } else {
        index = 0;
        loadTrack(index);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      }
    }),
    loadTrack = function(id) {
      npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
      index = id;
      audio.src = tracks[id].file;
    };
    loadTrack(index);
  }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3e4e2f11a7.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" role="main">
  <div id="cwrap">
    <div id="nowPlay" class="is-audio">
      <div id="npTitle"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="audiowrap">
      <div id="audio0">
        <audio id="audio1" controls preload="none"></audio>
      </div>
      <div id="extraControls" class="is-audio">
        <button id="btnPrev" class="ctrlbtn">|&lt;&lt; Prev Track</button> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" onclick="aud_play_pause()"><i id="stateicon" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
        <button id="btnNext" class="ctrlbtn">Next Track &gt;&gt;|</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a fiddle to your code or put your code in a snippet. It makes it much easier to replicate the behaviour you're talking about. Also consider referring to caniuse.com to check for any possible known issues with html5 audio.

Comment: I added my code here as a code snippet, I even can run it. I checked caniuse.com, everything is green for Safari and there is no known issue.

Comment: Well, i apologise then. I'm viewing on the android app and on the app there seems to be no functionality to add or run snippets..

Comment: No problem, I double checked the snippet here and it works as I asked in the question: Safari: not working; FF, Chrome: working.

Comment: @Adrian Please whats wrong with my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can put autoplay or after new src implement play in onload event like this :**

example :

```
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 

   audio.play();

}, false);
```

In code snippet i use autoplay atrr in audio tag !

```js
function aud_play_pause() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");
    if (myAudio.paused) {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-play');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-pause');
      myAudio.play();
    } else {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-pause');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-play');
      myAudio.pause();
   }
 }

$(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(function($) {
  var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
  if(supportsAudio) {
    var index = 0,
    playing = false;
    tracks = [
      {"track":1,"name":"Music FM","file":"http://stream.musicfm.hu:8000/musicfm.mp3"},
      {"track":2,"name":"Radio 1","file":"http://213.181.210.106:8000/high.mp3"},
      {"track":3,"name":"Test FM","file":"http://213.181.210.106:8000/high.mp3"},
    ],
    trackCount = tracks.length,
    npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
    audio = $('#audio1').bind('play', function() {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-play');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-pause');
      playing = true;
    }).bind('pause', function() {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-pause');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-play');
      playing = false;
    }).get(0),
    btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').click(function() {
      if((index - 1) > -1) {
        index--;
        loadTrack(index);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      } else {
        index = 0
        loadTrack(trackCount-1);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      }
    }),
    btnNext = $('#btnNext').click(function() {
      if((index + 1) < trackCount) {
        index++;
        loadTrack(index);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      } else {
        index = 0;
        loadTrack(index);
        if(playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      }
    }),
    loadTrack = function(id) {
      npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
      index = id;
      audio.src = tracks[id].file;
      /* JS method
       audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
        audio.play();
      }, false);*/

    };
    loadTrack(index);
  }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3e4e2f11a7.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" role="main">
  <div id="cwrap">
    <div id="nowPlay" class="is-audio">
      <div id="npTitle"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="audiowrap">
      <div id="audio0">
        <audio id="audio1" autoplay controls preload="none"></audio>
      </div>
      <div id="extraControls" class="is-audio">
        <button id="btnPrev" class="ctrlbtn">|&lt;&lt; Prev Track</button> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" onclick="aud_play_pause()"><i id="stateicon" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
        <button id="btnNext" class="ctrlbtn">Next Track &gt;&gt;|</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```